# Firebase query orderBy with multiple nodes

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch polls whose pollEndingTime is greater than the current time so for that reason I have used where query and in order to work where query I have applied orderBy on pollEndingTime also, but also I have to orderBy it in terms of totalVote received till now.
So my query is looking like this:

```
 query = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("polls")
          .where("pollEndingTime", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: Timestamp.now())
          .orderBy("pollEndingTime", descending: true)
          .orderBy("totalVote", descending: true);
```

Here there is no effect of orderBy on totalVote. So how can I achieve my goal to fetch polls based on totalVote in descending form and also their pollEndingTime is greater than or equal to current timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple `orderBy` statements in a single query, the database handles them in the order specified. So the results you get are *first* ordered by `pollEndingTime` and only then on `totalVote`. The consequence of this is that the ordering of `totalVote` is only visible for results that have the exact same `pollEndingTime`, which apparently wasn't the case in the data set that you tested with.

There is no alternative for this in the API, as it would require the server to reorder the data which it can't do at scale without violating its performance guarantees. So you will have to reorder the results in your application code after retrieving them, for example by calling [`sort`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/sort.html).